# How to inlucde external javascript libraries in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, openshift

I have a web page which needs to include external javascript libraries. I have downloaded them and include in the php->libraries folder. My application is hosted in openshift cloud. I want to include those javascript files in my php file. I have used this code

```
<script src=”../../libraries/dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxCalendar/codebase/dhtmlxcalendar.js”></script>
```

But it is not working

Then I tried

```
<script type=“text/javascript” src=”<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js” ></script>
```

The base url gives me the url but it is also not working.

What is the correct way for this ? I am a beginner for codeigniter. Could you help me

Comment: Change `“` and `”` characters to `"`.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
```

This should output:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

If the above still doesn't work, chances are the file cannot be found and it's in a different directory.

You could also use an [**asset helper**](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Asset-Helper) to added script files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a folder called 'assets' in your root CodeIgniter folder. Your root folder must now have these 4 folders: applications, assets, system, user_guide.
2. Create a folder called **js** and put your Javascript file there.
3. Then, open the config.php file located at \application\config\config.php.
4. Set the base url to your root folder. You can replace www.yoursite.com by localhost if your developing locally. /folder is the name of your root folder

   $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yoursite.com/folder/index.php';
5. Use this script in your view:

" >

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'..assets/js/javascriptfile.js'; ?>" ></script>
```

Just replace **javascriptfile** with the your js filename.

This is how I do it and it will surely work.

Comment: Could you rewrite the script part in step 5. and What do you mean by replacing ? You mean I have to give only the file name as the path of the javascript file ?

Comment: Also could you tel me how to set the base url to the rrot folder in config.php ?

Comment: wait. the php code I embedded is not working. how do you embed php code here? lol

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `.htaccess` file where you rewrite the access rules?

If so you must include the `.js` extension in that file (see below):

```
# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|txt|js|robots\.txt|images|css|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico|assets|forums)
```

Comment: yes, I have use this methos, updating  .htaccess file, but that was not working